# Bootstrap and responsive image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the following structure: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvYLpq
What I want to achieve is to make the image go left with `overflow: hidden` when I resize the page. It should look like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQvwEj
So basically I need to increase `margin-left` when I resize the window. So my question is how to make it without any javascript?

Comment: your question is how to detect the change in window size without javascript?

Comment: @reiallenramos not really. What I want is to make image go to the left side when I resize the window. I used `margin-left: -60px` and `overflow: hidden` as an example of how it should look when you change the size of the window.

Comment: in that case go with `@media` queries. @Bart has an example below